# How to construct Kotlin data class from blueprint class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

In my Spring Boot web app, there is an HTML form, which populates a `Blueprint` object:

```
data class Blueprint(

    // relevant part, validation omitted
    var items: List<Long> = emptyList() // List of ids

    // ...
)
```

Later on, I intend to use this `Blueprint` to create a `Product`, which would be a data class of similar structure:

```
data class Product(

    val items: List<Item>
    /* Here 'items' is a list of Item objects which are fetched from DB by */
    /* their ids. Item is data class too. */

)
```

I would like `Product` to take a `Blueprint` object as a constructor argument.

I tried to go with secondary constructor, but it requires me to call primary constructor right away, before I have a chance to process blueprint and possibly filter out some item ids.

There are of course workarounds, such as a factory function, but it seems reasonable to expect that I can just pass a blueprint to a constructor.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have three options here:

1. Adapter: `Blueprint.asProduct()`
2. Factory method: `Product.fromBlueprint(blueprint)`
3. Or simply: Product(blueprint.items.filter { /* something here */ }

It very much depends on what's the cardinality between `Product` and `Blueprint`

If you have many `Product` classes, then having factory method makes more sense.

If you usually create `Product` from `Blueprint`, then Adapter makes more sense.

If you can't figure it out, third option is also valid.

Comment: It seems factory pattern is indeed the way to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make a helper function inside a companion object, which provides the arguments for the primary constructor. Then call this helper in the secondary constructor:

```
data class Product(val items: List<Item>) {
    constructor(blueprint: Blueprint)
            : this(makeItems(blueprint))

    private companion object {
        fun makeItems(blueprint: Blueprint): List<Item> {
            return blueprint.items
               .filter { ... }
               .map { Item(...) }
        }
    }
}
```

If the conversion code is short, you can of course do it inline:

```
constructor(blueprint: Blueprint)
        : this(blueprint.items.filter { ... }.map { Item(...) })
```

Since you're dealing with a `data class` however, it might be clearer to really provide a factory `fromBlueprint()`, so that people immediately see that the passed argument is not a property. Alternatively, call the constructor with named arguments, as `Product(blueprint = ...)`.